# Capture failed tasks from Celery workers during task execution

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am currently using `Task.delay()` in celery (with RabbitMQ) to perform asynchronous tasks. The tasks are distributed to 8 workers, and in these tasks, I am performing a database insertion operation.

Sometimes a tasks will fail, and the database insertion does not happen. This can be due to a timeout or JSON decode errors. I want to capture that an execution has failed.

Here is the relevant code:

**views.py**

```
def celery_url_filtering(request):
    for each_data in dataset:
        #each_data is a Json object
        res = result.delay(each_data)
    while(res.status == 'PENDING'):
         pass
    return JsonResponse({'ok':'Success'})
```

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def result(dataeach_data):
    # Parse each_data  and do data insertion here
    return "Something"
```

How can I capture the failed executions in a list?

Comment: Why don't you handle those errors in your task?

Comment: @DejanLekic, The errors are random, so unable to trace the root cause

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from your concern is that you want to look into the "PENDING" or "FAILURE" tasks and to retry/apply some application logic.

If that is so, you can have a cron running at fixed schedule, daily/hourly etc, based on requirement. This cron job can capture the tasks that failed in last day/hour based on the schedule you have.

You can use [django-celery-beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for setting the cron job and [django-celery-results](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-results/) to store celery task results using Django ORM.

For example, you can have a celery task like this

```
from celery import shared_task
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult

**tasks.py**
@shared_task(name="failed_task_cron", bind=True)
def failed_task_cron(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Celery task to run on daily schedule to do something with the failed tasks
    """
    tasks = TaskResult.objects.filter(status='FAILURE')
    # tasks is a queryset of all the failed tasks
    # Perform application logic
```

You can set cron for the above task like this in your celery settings

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

# ...

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "failed_task_cron": {
        "task": "path/to/tasks.failed_task_cron",
        "schedule": crontab(hour=1)           # Runs every hour
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question above, If my data insertion in my every task fails due to JsonDecode errors, Does Celery categorize it under FAILED tasks????

Comment: Anything that causes a celery task to not complete, will lead in a FAILURE status. You can try checking the same using shell.

Comment: For now, let's say I don't want to implement crontab, so, I will just keep print this line "TaskResult.objects.filter(status='FAILURE')" before JsonResponse() in the function in views.py which is shown in the question...... Will it print the Failed tasks?

Comment: It will. Queryset of all the tasks failed. But that might be a huge set to manage over time! If you are doing some processing for those tasks, it's better to keep on getting rid of them over a period of time. Hence, comes the cron job.